# How to fetch data from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch data from two different tables, the thing 3 tables have in common is username field, here is what I've tried till now

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    post f1
        INNER JOIN
    portfolio f2 ON f1.username = f2.username
WHERE
    f1.username IN ('user1' , 'user2')
        OR f2.username IN ('user1' , 'user2');
```

All i want is if user1 has post data in `post` table & portfolio data in `portfolio` table then fetch all those detail

here is table structure

Post table

```
-------------------------------------------
| id  | username | content | title | time |
-------------------------------------------
|  1  |   user1  |   eg    | titl  | eg1  |
|  2  |   user2  |   eg    | title | eg2  |
|  3  |   user3  |   eg    | title | eg3  |
|  4  |   user1  |   eg1   | title | eg4  |
|  5  |   user5  |   eg    | title | eg5  |
|  6  |   user6  |   eg    | title | eg6  |
-------------------------------------------
```

Portfolio table

```
-------------------------------------------
| id  | username |  Image  | title | time |
-------------------------------------------
|  1  |   user1  |   eg    | titl  | eg1  |
|  2  |   user2  |   eg    | title | eg2  |
|  3  |   user4  |   eg    | title | eg3  |
|  4  |   user1  |   eg1   | title | eg4  |
|  5  |   user3  |   eg    | title | eg5  |
|  6  |   user6  |   eg    | title | eg6  |
-------------------------------------------
```

some of these user has data in post table also & portfolio table also so fetch the detail, how can i do it as my query is bringing duplicate data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only the firts condition    the inner join worok only if match in the two table

```
  SELECT distinct f1.*, f2.* 
  FROM post f1
  INNER JOIN portfolio f2 ON f1.username = f2.username
  WHERE  f1.username IN ('user1' , 'user2');
```

or

```
  SELECT distinct f1.*, f2.* 
  FROM post f1
  INNER JOIN portfolio f2 ON 
          (f1.username = f2.username and  f1.username IN ('user1' , 'user2'));
```

sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cfad/1

and second query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cfad/2

if you jave 3 table all with username in common you can use a double inner join

```
  SELECT distinct f1.*, f2.*, f3.* 
  FROM post f1
  INNER JOIN portfolio f2 ON f1.username = f2.username
  INNER JOIN table2 f3 on f1.username = f3.username
  WHERE  f1.username IN ('user1' , 'user2');
```

Comment: Your query is only returning user1 data not user2

Comment: Based on the sample  you provided .my query should return both  .. where is  IN ('user1' , 'user2')  ..check for proper data .. in your test case

Comment: there is something wrong in query should i show you on sqlfiddle?

Comment: i have update the query with ref .. to sqlfiddle .. and like you can check the query work

Comment: Okay thanks what if there is a third table how can i integrated third table in it

Comment: Of course if you have other table you can "integrate" these table by proper join .. there are not (reasonable ) limit to table join in relational db ..

Comment: 3rd table also have username in common, so how could integrate it?

Comment: I want to know one more thing, if there is a result found in post table then why portfolio field is shown in the right of post field with duplicate value? check the update fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/515d6b/1 i have removed last 4 rows

Comment: because the select contain  f1.* and f2.*  .. f2,* mean all the column of the tbale f2 alias portfolio . in your case are duplicated because your porfolio table seem a copy of post .. hope is clear ..

Comment: check the fiddle please http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66fb5d/1/0 i have removed last 4 now only 2 result are shown but there should be shown 6

Comment: No the rows select are correct .. in your fiddle you are select the   distinct rows for username user1  and use2 .. that match in both the table   .. the distinct rows are 2  .. try removing distinct  ..

Comment: still same! see let me tell you the problem if you see in fiddle there are three records of user1 user2 which is totally correct but in post table there is two records but there is shown 3 records... now you understand?

Comment: chech the fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66fb5d/1/0  there are only two rows valid one for user1 and one for user2  .. not 3

Comment: but there may be many user with same username in table as they can post as many times they want check again http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f5bf/1

Comment: Now you have 3 rows because you have 1 for user1 and 2 for user2  this is correct .. i don't undertsand  the where is problem  .. in relational  db this is correct ..

Comment: i only want to fetch the data where username ='$user1' or user2

Comment: Ok but this happen in the fiddle .. whats the problem .. you don't want the second row for user2.. ?

Comment: See i have a timeline where user1 & user2 are my friends so i want to see their post & portfolio at my timeline nothing else.. i hope you understand

Comment: Ok .. but the fiddle show only the post and portfoglio for user1 and user2 .. so i don't understand  what 's the problem now ..

Comment: in portfolio table try replacing user6 with user2 you will see that in portfolio there will be 3 matched result but in post table also there is shown 3 result but there was only 2 match in post table

Comment: Ok  .. and this is correct .. what's the problem .. if you want only two rows instead of select *  perform the  select distinct the column without the id ..  and you get only two rows.

Comment: sorry i didn't get it how?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT *
FROM
    post f1
        INNER JOIN
    portfolio f2 ON f1.username = f2.username
WHERE
    f1.username IN ('user1' , 'user2')
        OR f2.username IN ('user1' , 'user2');
```

Comment: your query is returning duplicate data

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code? This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.